# How can I force a browser/site to not delete files it needs downloaded in order to run a browser game (keep its' cache)?

Tags: browser, download, opera

I'm playing a game in my browser (Opera) and it has a lot of menus etc. Some menus have images on them and every single time I visit that menu, the game has to run like 3 downloads to download those 3 images that appear in that menu (the images dont appear untill after the information about downloading disappears), even though it has already downloaded them many times in the past. It doesnt happen with everything, of course, some images are saved permanently and dont require these repeated downloads.

I'm wondering if I can somehow force the browser not to get rid of any files that specific website downloads? I'm not sure if cache mentioned in the title is related here, in case you were confused.

Comment: Forcing a website to do something does not seem appropriate for this site.